# Using VueJS with Axios post response data disappears

Tags: javascript, python, vue.js, python-3.6, axios

I have been trying to figure out how to use VueJS, Axios and Python together. I can make a post request to the python file just fine. When I click the submit button, the response data shows correctly, but only for a second and then disappears. Why is this?

**insert.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
import os
import sys
import json

parsed_json = json.loads(sys.stdin.read())    
print ("Content-type: text/html\n")
print(parsed_json['firstName'])
print(parsed_json['lastName'])
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>index.html</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form id="example-1">
   <input type="text" ref="firstName">
   <input type="text" ref="lastName">
   <button v-on:click="submit">Submit</button>
   {{ output }}
  </form>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  <script>
   var example1 = new Vue({
    el: '#example-1',
    data: {
     output: ''
    },
    methods: {
     submit: function () {
      axios.post('/cgi-bin/insert.py', {
       firstName: this.$refs.firstName.value,
        lastName: this.$refs.lastName.value
      })
      .then(response => {
       this.output = response.data;
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
       console.log(error);
      });
     }
    }
   }) 
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your button to `type="button"`.

```
<button type="button" v-on:click="submit">Submit</button>
```

The default button type is "submit" which results in a refresh of your page.

Alternatively you can use the .prevent modifier.

```
<button v-on:click.prevent="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Well that makes perfect sense, can not believe I did not think of that. I was wondering why the page was refreshing every time. Silly mistake, thank you so much! Saved me a headache, I thought I was doing something wrong with VueJS/Axios!

Comment: @antfuentes87 Been there :)